# How can I assign values to attributes in a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been able to assign values to specific elements by ID in forms. For example...

```
form1.textbox1.value = "Hello";
```

Now this works, when the HTML looks like this...

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" id="textbox1" />
</form>
```

It also works when you use name instead of ID. Now my issue is, I want to replicate this but with a table. Why doesn't this work?...

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
<td id="cell1"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
    </form>

table1.cell1.value = "Hello";
```

I don't see why it doesn't work. The problem here is, I need to be able to create a function, input my own parameters that allow me to change the first name or ID (whatever method is being used) in this line of code >(`table1.cell1.value`) as there are clones of this table with the same ID or name (eg. table1, table2, table3) So the parameters can change allowing me to input data through a prompt every time a new clone of the table is created on the click of a button. The cloning works perfectly, the new table comes up properly, it even changed the ID of the table. All I need is help to understand how to use the (`table1.cell1.value`) method to set a cell's value.

Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 2):

Input fields have `value` but non-input elements have [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) or [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). If IE8 support is not required, you can use `textContent` (or use a polyfill to add support). Then you can do:

```
table1.cell1.textContent = "Hello";
```

Or more likely:

```
document.getElementById('cell1').textContent = 'Hello';
```

If you want HTML, you'll need to use `innerHTML` in the same way.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work, I tried it. The prompt came up but the cell that was supposed to be filled with its value was left the same. It didn't change?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tag you @Cymen

Comment: You have a lot of questions in one question :)

Comment: Sorry, are you still able to help?

Comment: I forgot to tag you again

Comment: I didn't even type your name in @Cymen

Comment: @PleaseHelp I'd suggest putting your code up on a site like jsfiddle.net so other people can see what you're trying to do. We are all answering how to write to a dom element. Your other questions should probably be posted as new questions with specific examples. That way you'll get more help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
<td id="cell1">cell1</td>
<td>cell2</td>
</tr>
<script>
var table = document.getElementById('table1');
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

var objectHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("td"),
    string = [].map.call( objectHTMLCollection, function(node){
        return node.textContent || node.innerText || "";
    }).join("");
document.write(string);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I am looking for, the first answer is more what I am looking for...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write

```
    var td = document.getElementById("tdId");
    td.innerHTML = "James Bond is cool";
```

Comment: I can't do this as I need to identify which table the value goes to, there are clones so it will assign it to every table because it assigns staright to that one ID. If you use the other method I want, I can use a function with parameters to change the table ID, whenever I call the function.

Comment: Then you probably need to have composite id system , like table ids and for every table row and td Ids.